# Iterate over JSON object with JavaScript is not working with this data

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON data below which I am trying to iterate over using JavaScript.

I have a JSFiddle demo set up here https://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/mnjm9fyh/

I have tried pretty much everything I can find in a Google or Stack Overflow search to iterate and show this data but have had no luck so far.

There seems to be some sort of issue somewhere. How can I get the desired result of iterating this data with JavaScript?

```
var technology = {
    "apps": {
        "1und1": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "1und1.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "url": "/shop/catalog/browse\\?sessid=",
            "website": "1und1.de"
        },
        "3dCart": {
            "cats": [
                1,
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "3dvisit",
                "X-Powered-By": "3DCART"
            },
            "icon": "3dCart.png",
            "script": "(?:twlh(?:track)?\\.asp|3d_upsell\\.js)",
            "website": "www.3dcart.com"
        },
        "Arastta": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "excludes": "OpenCart",
            "headers": {
                "Arastta": "(.*)\\;version:\\1",
                "X-Arastta": "\\;version:1.2.1+"
            },
            "html": "Powered by <a [^>]*href=\"https?://(?:www\\.)?arastta\\.org[^>]+>Arastta",
            "icon": "Arastta.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "script": "arastta\\.js",
            "website": "arastta.org"
        },
        "Avangate": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^(?:__)?avng8_",
            "html": "<link[^>]* href=\"^https?://edge\\.avangate\\.net/",
            "icon": "Avangate.png",
            "script": "^https?://edge\\.avangate\\.net/",
            "website": "avangate.com"
        },
        "Bigcommerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^compareProducts$",
            "html": "<link href=[^>]+cdn\\d+\\.bigcommerce\\.com/v",
            "icon": "Bigcommerce.png",
            "script": "cdn\\d+\\.bigcommerce\\.com/v",
            "url": "mybigcommerce\\.com",
            "website": "www.bigcommerce.com"
        },
        "Bigware": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "(?:bigwareCsid|bigWAdminID)"
            },
            "html": "(?:Diese <a href=[^>]+bigware\\.de|<a href=[^>]+/main_bigware_\\d+\\.php)",
            "icon": "Bigware.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "url": "(?:\\?|&)bigWAdminID=",
            "website": "bigware.de"
        },
        "Blesta": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "blesta_sid"
            },
            "icon": "Blesta.png",
            "website": "www.blesta.com"
        },
        "CS Cart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^fn_compare_strings$",
            "html": [
                "&nbsp;Powered by (?:<a href=[^>]+cs-cart\\.com|CS-Cart)",
                ".cm-noscript[^>]+</style>"
            ],
            "icon": "CS Cart.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "website": "www.cs-cart.com"
        },
        "Clientexec": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "clientexec\\.[^>]*\\s?=\\s?[^>]*;",
            "icon": "Clientexec.png",
            "website": "www.clientexec.com"
        },
        "Commerce Server": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "COMMERCE-SERVER-SOFTWARE": ""
            },
            "icon": "Commerce Server.png",
            "implies": "Microsoft ASP.NET",
            "website": "commerceserver.net"
        },
        "Cosmoshop": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Cosmoshop.png",
            "script": "cosmoshop_functions\\.js",
            "website": "cosmoshop.de"
        },
        "CubeCart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "(?:Powered by <a href=[^>]+cubecart\\.com|<p[^>]+>Powered by CubeCart)",
            "icon": "CubeCart.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "cubecart"
            },
            "website": "www.cubecart.com"
        },
        "Demandware": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^dwAnalytics$",
            "headers": {
                "Server": "Demandware eCommerce Server"
            },
            "html": "<[^>]+demandware\\.edgesuite",
            "icon": "Demandware.png",
            "website": "demandware.com"
        },
        "Drupal Commerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<[^>]+(?:id=\"block[_-]commerce[_-]cart[_-]cart|class=\"commerce[_-]product[_-]field)",
            "icon": "Drupal Commerce.png",
            "implies": "Drupal",
            "website": "drupalcommerce.org"
        },
        "E-Merchant": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "E-Merchant.png",
            "script": "cdn\\.e-merchant\\.com",
            "website": "e-merchant.com"
        },
        "Elcodi": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "X-Elcodi": ""
            },
            "icon": "Elcodi.png",
            "implies": [
                "PHP",
                "Symfony"
            ],
            "website": "elcodi.io"
        },
        "FWP": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<!--\\s+FwP Systems",
            "icon": "FWP.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "FWP Shop"
            },
            "website": "fwpshop.org"
        },
        "Fortune3": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "(?:<link [^>]*href=\"[^\\/]*\\/\\/www\\.fortune3\\.com\\/[^\"]*siterate\\/rate\\.css|Powered by <a [^>]*href=\"[^\"]+fortune3\\.com)",
            "icon": "Fortune3.png",
            "script": "cartjs\\.php\\?(?:.*&)?s=[^&]*myfortune3cart\\.com",
            "website": "fortune3.com"
        },
        "Gambio": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^gm_session_id$",
            "html": "(?:<link[^>]* href=\"templates/gambio/|<a[^>]content\\.php\\?coID=\\d|<!-- gambio eof -->|<!--[\\s=]+Shopsoftware by Gambio GmbH \\(c\\))",
            "icon": "Gambio.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "script": "gm_javascript\\.js\\.php",
            "website": "gambio.de"
        },
        "Hybris": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "_hybris"
            },
            "html": "<[^>]+(?:/sys_master/|/hybr/|/_ui/desktop/)",
            "icon": "Hybris.png",
            "implies": "Java",
            "website": "hybris.com"
        },
        "IBM WebSphere Commerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "IBM WebSphere Commerce.png",
            "implies": "Java",
            "url": "/wcs/",
            "website": "ibm.com/software/genservers/commerceproductline"
        },
        "Intershop": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Intershop.png",
            "script": "(?:is-bin|INTERSHOP)",
            "website": "intershop.com"
        },
        "JTL Shop": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "JTLSHOP="
            },
            "html": "(?:<input[^>]+name=\"JTLSHOP|<a href=\"jtl\\.php)",
            "icon": "JTL Shop.png",
            "website": "www.jtl-software.de/produkte/jtl-shop3"
        },
        "Magento": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^(?:Mage|VarienForm)$",
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "frontend=\\;confidence:50"
            },
            "icon": "Magento.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "script": [
                "js/mage",
                "skin/frontend/(?:default|(enterprise))\\;version:\\1?Enterprise:Community"
            ],
            "website": "www.magentocommerce.com"
        },
        "Moguta.CMS": {
            "cats": [
                1,
                6
            ],
            "html": "(?:<script|link)[^>]*mg-(?:core|plugins|templates)",
            "icon": "Moguta.CMS.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "website": "moguta.ru"
        },
        "Mondo Media": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Mondo Media.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "Mondo Shop"
            },
            "website": "mondo-media.de"
        },
        "Netsuite": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "NS_VER="
            },
            "icon": "Netsuite.png",
            "website": "netsuite.com"
        },
        "OXID eShop": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^ox(?:TopMenu|ModalPopup|LoginBox|InputValidator)",
            "html": "<!--[^-]*OXID eShop",
            "icon": "OXID eShop.png",
            "website": "oxid-esales.com"
        },
        "Odoo": {
            "cats": [
                1,
                6
            ],
            "html": "<link[^>]* href=[^>]+/web/css/(?:web\\.assets_common/|website\\.assets_frontend/)\\;confidence:25",
            "icon": "Odoo.png",
            "implies": [
                "Python",
                "PostgreSQL",
                "node.js",
                "Less"
            ],
            "meta": {
                "generator": "Odoo"
            },
            "script": "/web/js/(?:web\\.assets_common/|website\\.assets_frontend/)\\;confidence:25",
            "website": "odoo.com"
        },
        "Open Classifieds": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Open Classifieds.png",
            "meta": {
                "author": "open-classifieds\\.com",
                "copyright": "Open Classifieds ?([0-9.]+)?\\;version:\\1"
            },
            "website": "open-classifieds.com"
        },
        "Open eShop": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Open eShop.png",
            "meta": {
                "author": "open-eshop\\.com",
                "copyright": "Open eShop ?([0-9.]+)?\\;version:\\1"
            },
            "website": "open-eshop.com/"
        },
        "OpenCart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "(?:index\\.php\\?route=[a-z]+/|Powered By <a href=\"[^>]+OpenCart)",
            "icon": "OpenCart.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "website": "www.opencart.com"
        },
        "Oracle Commerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "X-ATG-Version": "(?:ATGPlatform/([\\d.]+))?\\;version:\\1"
            },
            "html": "<[^>]+_dyncharset",
            "icon": "Oracle Commerce.png",
            "website": "www.oracle.com/applications/customer-experience/commerce/products/commerce-platform/index.html"
        },
        "Oracle Commerce Cloud": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "OracleCommerceCloud-Version": "(.*)\\;version:\\1"
            },
            "html": "<[^>]+id=\"oracle-cc\"",
            "icon": "Oracle Commerce Cloud.png",
            "website": "cloud.oracle.com/commerce-cloud"
        },
        "Plentymarkets": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Plentymarkets.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "plentymarkets"
            },
            "website": "plentymarkets.eu"
        },
        "Powergap": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": [
                "<a[^>]+title=\"POWERGAP",
                "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"shopid\""
            ],
            "icon": "Powergap.png",
            "website": "powergap.de"
        },
        "PrestaShop": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "Powered by <a\\s+[^>]+>PrestaShop",
            "icon": "PrestaShop.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "PrestaShop"
            },
            "website": "www.prestashop.com"
        },
        "Quick.Cart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<a href=\"[^>]+opensolution\\.org/\">(?:Shopping cart by|Sklep internetowy)",
            "icon": "Quick.Cart.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "Quick\\.Cart(?: v([\\d.]+))?\\;version:\\1"
            },
            "website": "opensolution.org"
        },
        "RBS Change": {
            "cats": [
                1,
                6
            ],
            "html": "<html[^>]+xmlns:change=",
            "icon": "RBS Change.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "RBS Change"
            },
            "website": "www.rbschange.fr"
        },
        "Seoshop": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<a[^>]+title=\"SEOshop",
            "icon": "Seoshop.png",
            "website": "getseoshop.com"
        },
        "Shopatron": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^shptUrl$",
            "html": [
                "<body class=\"shopatron",
                "<img[^>]+mediacdn\\.shopatron\\.com\\;confidence:50"
            ],
            "icon": "Shopatron.png",
            "meta": {
                "keywords": "Shopatron"
            },
            "script": "mediacdn\\.shopatron\\.com",
            "website": "ecommerce.shopatron.com"
        },
        "Shopify": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^Shopify$",
            "html": "<link[^>]+=['\"]//cdn\\.shopify\\.com",
            "icon": "Shopify.png",
            "website": "shopify.com"
        },
        "Shoptet": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^shoptet$",
            "html": "<link [^>]*href=\"https?://cdn\\.myshoptet\\.com/",
            "icon": "Shoptet.svg",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "meta": {
                "web_author": "^Shoptet"
            },
            "script": [
                "^https?://cdn\\.myshoptet\\.com/"
            ],
            "website": "www.shoptet.cz"
        },
        "Shopware": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Shopware.png",
            "implies": [
                "PHP",
                "MySQL",
                "jQuery"
            ],
            "meta": {
                "application-name": "Shopware"
            },
            "script": "(?:(shopware)|/web/cache/[0-9]{10}_.+)\\.js\\;version:\\1?4:5",
            "website": "shopware.com"
        },
        "Smartstore": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Smartstore.png",
            "script": "smjslib\\.js",
            "website": "smartstore.com"
        },
        "Spree": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "(?:<link[^>]*/assets/store/all-[a-z\\d]{32}\\.css[^>]+>|<script>\\s*Spree\\.(?:routes|translations|api_key))",
            "icon": "Spree.png",
            "implies": "Ruby on Rails",
            "website": "spreecommerce.com"
        },
        "Store Systems": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "Shopsystem von <a href=[^>]+store-systems\\.de\"|\\.mws_boxTop",
            "icon": "Store Systems.png",
            "website": "store-systems.de"
        },
        "Thelia": {
            "cats": [
                1,
                6
            ],
            "html": "<(?:link|style|script)[^>]+/assets/frontOffice/",
            "icon": "Thelia.png",
            "implies": [
                "PHP",
                "Symfony"
            ],
            "website": "thelia.net"
        },
        "TomatoCart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^AjaxShoppingCart$",
            "icon": "TomatoCart.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "TomatoCart"
            },
            "website": "tomatocart.com"
        },
        "Ubercart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Ubercart.png",
            "implies": "Drupal",
            "script": "uc_cart/uc_cart_block\\.js",
            "website": "www.ubercart.org"
        },
        "UltraCart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^ucCatalog",
            "html": "<form [^>]*action=\"[^\"]*\\/cgi-bin\\/UCEditor\\?(?:[^\"]*&)?merchantId=[^\"]",
            "icon": "UltraCart.png",
            "script": "cgi-bin\\/UCJavaScript\\?(?:[^\"]*&)?merchantid=.",
            "url": "/cgi-bin/UCEditor\\?(?:.*&)?merchantid=.",
            "website": "ultracart.com"
        },
        "VP-ASP": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<a[^>]+>Powered By VP-ASP Shopping Cart</a>",
            "icon": "VP-ASP.png",
            "implies": "Microsoft ASP.NET",
            "script": "vs350\\.js",
            "website": "www.vpasp.com"
        },
        "VTEX Enterprise": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "powered": "vtex"
            },
            "icon": "VTEX Enterprise.png",
            "website": "vtex.com"
        },
        "VTEX Integrated Store": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "X-Powered-By": "vtex-integrated-store"
            },
            "icon": "VTEX Integrated Store.png",
            "website": "lojaintegrada.com.br"
        },
        "Venda": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "X-venda-hitid": ""
            },
            "icon": "Venda.png",
            "website": "venda.com"
        },
        "VirtueMart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<div id=\"vmMainPage",
            "icon": "VirtueMart.png",
            "implies": "Joomla",
            "website": "virtuemart.net"
        },
        "Volusion": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^volusion$",
            "html": "<link [^>]*href=\"[^\"]*/vspfiles/",
            "icon": "Volusion.png",
            "script": "/volusion\\.js(?:\\?([\\d.]*))?\\;version:\\1",
            "website": "volusion.com"
        },
        "WHMCS": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "^WHMCS.*"
            },
            "icon": "WHMCS.png",
            "website": "www.whmcs.com"
        },
        "Websale": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Websale.png",
            "url": "/websale7/",
            "website": "websale.de"
        },
        "WooCommerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "woocommerce",
            "html": "<!-- WooCommerce",
            "icon": "WooCommerce.png",
            "implies": [
                "WordPress",
                "PHP"
            ],
            "meta": {
                "generator": "WooCommerce ([\\d.]+)\\;version:\\1"
            },
            "script": "woocommerce",
            "website": "www.woothemes.com/woocommerce"
        },
        "X-Cart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^(?:xcart_web_dir|xliteConfig)$",
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "xid=[a-z\\d]{32}(?:;|$)"
            },
            "html": [
                "Powered by X-Cart(?: (\\d+))? <a[^>]+href=\"http://www\\.x-cart\\.com/\"[^>]*>\\;version:\\1",
                "<a[^>]+href=\"[^\"]*(?:\\?|&)xcart_form_id=[a-z\\d]{32}(?:&|$)"
            ],
            "icon": "X-Cart.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "X-Cart(?: (\\d+))?\\;version:\\1"
            },
            "script": "/skin/common_files/modules/Product_Options/func\\.js",
            "website": "x-cart.com"
        },
        "Xanario": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Xanario.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "xanario shopsoftware"
            },
            "website": "xanario.de"
        },
        "Yahoo! Ecommerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^YStore$",
            "headers": {
                "X-XRDS-Location": "/ystore/"
            },
            "html": "<link[^>]+store\\.yahoo\\.net",
            "icon": "Yahoo! Ecommerce.png",
            "website": "smallbusiness.yahoo.com/ecommerce"
        },
        "Zen Cart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Zen Cart.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "Zen Cart"
            },
            "website": "www.zen-cart.com"
        },
        "Zeuscart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<form name=\"product\" method=\"post\" action=\"[^\"]+\\?do=addtocart&prodid=\\d+\"(?!<\\/form>.)+<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"addtocart\" value=\"\\d+\">",
            "icon": "Zeuscart.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "url": "\\?do=prodetail&action=show&prodid=\\d+",
            "website": "zeuscart.com"
        },
        "eZ Publish": {
            "cats": [
                1,
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "X-Powered-By": "^eZ Publish"
            },
            "icon": "eZ Publish.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "eZ Publish"
            },
            "website": "ez.no"
        },
        "iCongo": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "iCongo.png",
            "implies": "Adobe ColdFusion",
            "meta": {
                "iCongo": ""
            },
            "website": "hybris.com/icongo"
        },
        "nopCommerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "(?:<!--Powered by nopCommerce|Powered by: <a[^>]+nopcommerce)",
            "icon": "nopCommerce.png",
            "website": "www.nopcommerce.com"
        },
        "osCSS": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<body onload=\"window\\.defaultStatus='oscss templates';\"",
            "icon": "osCSS.png",
            "website": "www.oscss.org"
        },
        "osCommerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "osCsid="
            },
            "html": "(?:<a[^>]*(?:\\?|&)osCsid|Powered by (?:<[^>]+>)?osCommerce</a>|<[^>]+class=\"[^>]*infoBoxHeading)",
            "icon": "osCommerce.png",
            "website": "www.oscommerce.com"
        },
        "xtCommerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<div class=\"copyright\">[^<]+<a[^>]+>xt:Commerce",
            "icon": "xtCommerce.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "xt:Commerce"
            },
            "website": "www.xt-commerce.com"
        },
    }
};
```

Comment: How actually you want to Iterate my dear!...

Comment: JSONLint shows an error with your trailing comma on the last xtCommerce object. It may be that depending on how you are trying to iterate.

Comment: yes its correct remove that comma... its error while validate JSON

Comment: This line is the problem, I am still trying to understand why - "html": "(?:<link[^>]*/assets/store/all-[a-z\\d]{32}\\.css[^>]+>|<script>\\s*Spree\\.(?:routes|translations|api_key))", - http://codepen.io/dmoojunk/pen/wGQMNa?editors=0011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I don't know if I had get the idea. I hope this is what you are looking for

```
    var technology = {
    "apps": {
        "1und1": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "1und1.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "url": "/shop/catalog/browse\\?sessid=",
            "website": "1und1.de"
        },
        "3dCart": {
            "cats": [
                1,
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "3dvisit",
                "X-Powered-By": "3DCART"
            },
            "icon": "3dCart.png",
            "script": "(?:twlh(?:track)?\\.asp|3d_upsell\\.js)",
            "website": "www.3dcart.com"
        },
        "Arastta": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "excludes": "OpenCart",
            "headers": {
                "Arastta": "(.*)\\;version:\\1",
                "X-Arastta": "\\;version:1.2.1+"
            },
            "html": "Powered by <a [^>]*href=\"https?://(?:www\\.)?arastta\\.org[^>]+>Arastta",
            "icon": "Arastta.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "script": "arastta\\.js",
            "website": "arastta.org"
        },
        "Avangate": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^(?:__)?avng8_",
            "html": "<link[^>]* href=\"^https?://edge\\.avangate\\.net/",
            "icon": "Avangate.png",
            "script": "^https?://edge\\.avangate\\.net/",
            "website": "avangate.com"
        },
        "Bigcommerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^compareProducts$",
            "html": "<link href=[^>]+cdn\\d+\\.bigcommerce\\.com/v",
            "icon": "Bigcommerce.png",
            "script": "cdn\\d+\\.bigcommerce\\.com/v",
            "url": "mybigcommerce\\.com",
            "website": "www.bigcommerce.com"
        },
        "Bigware": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "(?:bigwareCsid|bigWAdminID)"
            },
            "html": "(?:Diese <a href=[^>]+bigware\\.de|<a href=[^>]+/main_bigware_\\d+\\.php)",
            "icon": "Bigware.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "url": "(?:\\?|&)bigWAdminID=",
            "website": "bigware.de"
        },
        "Blesta": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "blesta_sid"
            },
            "icon": "Blesta.png",
            "website": "www.blesta.com"
        },
        "CS Cart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^fn_compare_strings$",
            "html": [
                "&nbsp;Powered by (?:<a href=[^>]+cs-cart\\.com|CS-Cart)",
                ".cm-noscript[^>]+</style>"
            ],
            "icon": "CS Cart.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "website": "www.cs-cart.com"
        },
        "Clientexec": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "clientexec\\.[^>]*\\s?=\\s?[^>]*;",
            "icon": "Clientexec.png",
            "website": "www.clientexec.com"
        },
        "Commerce Server": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "COMMERCE-SERVER-SOFTWARE": ""
            },
            "icon": "Commerce Server.png",
            "implies": "Microsoft ASP.NET",
            "website": "commerceserver.net"
        },
        "Cosmoshop": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Cosmoshop.png",
            "script": "cosmoshop_functions\\.js",
            "website": "cosmoshop.de"
        },
        "CubeCart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "(?:Powered by <a href=[^>]+cubecart\\.com|<p[^>]+>Powered by CubeCart)",
            "icon": "CubeCart.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "cubecart"
            },
            "website": "www.cubecart.com"
        },
        "Demandware": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^dwAnalytics$",
            "headers": {
                "Server": "Demandware eCommerce Server"
            },
            "html": "<[^>]+demandware\\.edgesuite",
            "icon": "Demandware.png",
            "website": "demandware.com"
        },
        "Drupal Commerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<[^>]+(?:id=\"block[_-]commerce[_-]cart[_-]cart|class=\"commerce[_-]product[_-]field)",
            "icon": "Drupal Commerce.png",
            "implies": "Drupal",
            "website": "drupalcommerce.org"
        },
        "E-Merchant": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "E-Merchant.png",
            "script": "cdn\\.e-merchant\\.com",
            "website": "e-merchant.com"
        },
        "Elcodi": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "X-Elcodi": ""
            },
            "icon": "Elcodi.png",
            "implies": [
                "PHP",
                "Symfony"
            ],
            "website": "elcodi.io"
        },
        "FWP": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<!--\\s+FwP Systems",
            "icon": "FWP.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "FWP Shop"
            },
            "website": "fwpshop.org"
        },
        "Fortune3": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "(?:<link [^>]*href=\"[^\\/]*\\/\\/www\\.fortune3\\.com\\/[^\"]*siterate\\/rate\\.css|Powered by <a [^>]*href=\"[^\"]+fortune3\\.com)",
            "icon": "Fortune3.png",
            "script": "cartjs\\.php\\?(?:.*&)?s=[^&]*myfortune3cart\\.com",
            "website": "fortune3.com"
        },
        "Gambio": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^gm_session_id$",
            "html": "(?:<link[^>]* href=\"templates/gambio/|<a[^>]content\\.php\\?coID=\\d|<!-- gambio eof -->|<!--[\\s=]+Shopsoftware by Gambio GmbH \\(c\\))",
            "icon": "Gambio.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "script": "gm_javascript\\.js\\.php",
            "website": "gambio.de"
        },
        "Hybris": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "_hybris"
            },
            "html": "<[^>]+(?:/sys_master/|/hybr/|/_ui/desktop/)",
            "icon": "Hybris.png",
            "implies": "Java",
            "website": "hybris.com"
        },
        "IBM WebSphere Commerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "IBM WebSphere Commerce.png",
            "implies": "Java",
            "url": "/wcs/",
            "website": "ibm.com/software/genservers/commerceproductline"
        },
        "Intershop": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Intershop.png",
            "script": "(?:is-bin|INTERSHOP)",
            "website": "intershop.com"
        },
        "JTL Shop": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "JTLSHOP="
            },
            "html": "(?:<input[^>]+name=\"JTLSHOP|<a href=\"jtl\\.php)",
            "icon": "JTL Shop.png",
            "website": "www.jtl-software.de/produkte/jtl-shop3"
        },
        "Magento": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^(?:Mage|VarienForm)$",
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "frontend=\\;confidence:50"
            },
            "icon": "Magento.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "script": [
                "js/mage",
                "skin/frontend/(?:default|(enterprise))\\;version:\\1?Enterprise:Community"
            ],
            "website": "www.magentocommerce.com"
        },
        "Moguta.CMS": {
            "cats": [
                1,
                6
            ],
            "html": "(?:<script|link)[^>]*mg-(?:core|plugins|templates)",
            "icon": "Moguta.CMS.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "website": "moguta.ru"
        },
        "Mondo Media": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Mondo Media.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "Mondo Shop"
            },
            "website": "mondo-media.de"
        },
        "Netsuite": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "NS_VER="
            },
            "icon": "Netsuite.png",
            "website": "netsuite.com"
        },
        "OXID eShop": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^ox(?:TopMenu|ModalPopup|LoginBox|InputValidator)",
            "html": "<!--[^-]*OXID eShop",
            "icon": "OXID eShop.png",
            "website": "oxid-esales.com"
        },
        "Odoo": {
            "cats": [
                1,
                6
            ],
            "html": "<link[^>]* href=[^>]+/web/css/(?:web\\.assets_common/|website\\.assets_frontend/)\\;confidence:25",
            "icon": "Odoo.png",
            "implies": [
                "Python",
                "PostgreSQL",
                "node.js",
                "Less"
            ],
            "meta": {
                "generator": "Odoo"
            },
            "script": "/web/js/(?:web\\.assets_common/|website\\.assets_frontend/)\\;confidence:25",
            "website": "odoo.com"
        },
        "Open Classifieds": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Open Classifieds.png",
            "meta": {
                "author": "open-classifieds\\.com",
                "copyright": "Open Classifieds ?([0-9.]+)?\\;version:\\1"
            },
            "website": "open-classifieds.com"
        },
        "Open eShop": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Open eShop.png",
            "meta": {
                "author": "open-eshop\\.com",
                "copyright": "Open eShop ?([0-9.]+)?\\;version:\\1"
            },
            "website": "open-eshop.com/"
        },
        "OpenCart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "(?:index\\.php\\?route=[a-z]+/|Powered By <a href=\"[^>]+OpenCart)",
            "icon": "OpenCart.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "website": "www.opencart.com"
        },
        "Oracle Commerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "X-ATG-Version": "(?:ATGPlatform/([\\d.]+))?\\;version:\\1"
            },
            "html": "<[^>]+_dyncharset",
            "icon": "Oracle Commerce.png",
            "website": "www.oracle.com/applications/customer-experience/commerce/products/commerce-platform/index.html"
        },
        "Oracle Commerce Cloud": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "OracleCommerceCloud-Version": "(.*)\\;version:\\1"
            },
            "html": "<[^>]+id=\"oracle-cc\"",
            "icon": "Oracle Commerce Cloud.png",
            "website": "cloud.oracle.com/commerce-cloud"
        },
        "Plentymarkets": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Plentymarkets.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "plentymarkets"
            },
            "website": "plentymarkets.eu"
        },
        "Powergap": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": [
                "<a[^>]+title=\"POWERGAP",
                "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"shopid\""
            ],
            "icon": "Powergap.png",
            "website": "powergap.de"
        },
        "PrestaShop": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "Powered by <a\\s+[^>]+>PrestaShop",
            "icon": "PrestaShop.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "PrestaShop"
            },
            "website": "www.prestashop.com"
        },
        "Quick.Cart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<a href=\"[^>]+opensolution\\.org/\">(?:Shopping cart by|Sklep internetowy)",
            "icon": "Quick.Cart.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "Quick\\.Cart(?: v([\\d.]+))?\\;version:\\1"
            },
            "website": "opensolution.org"
        },
        "RBS Change": {
            "cats": [
                1,
                6
            ],
            "html": "<html[^>]+xmlns:change=",
            "icon": "RBS Change.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "RBS Change"
            },
            "website": "www.rbschange.fr"
        },
        "Seoshop": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<a[^>]+title=\"SEOshop",
            "icon": "Seoshop.png",
            "website": "getseoshop.com"
        },
        "Shopatron": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^shptUrl$",
            "html": [
                "<body class=\"shopatron",
                "<img[^>]+mediacdn\\.shopatron\\.com\\;confidence:50"
            ],
            "icon": "Shopatron.png",
            "meta": {
                "keywords": "Shopatron"
            },
            "script": "mediacdn\\.shopatron\\.com",
            "website": "ecommerce.shopatron.com"
        },
        "Shopify": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^Shopify$",
            "html": "<link[^>]+=['\"]//cdn\\.shopify\\.com",
            "icon": "Shopify.png",
            "website": "shopify.com"
        },
        "Shoptet": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^shoptet$",
            "html": "<link [^>]*href=\"https?://cdn\\.myshoptet\\.com/",
            "icon": "Shoptet.svg",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "meta": {
                "web_author": "^Shoptet"
            },
            "script": [
                "^https?://cdn\\.myshoptet\\.com/"
            ],
            "website": "www.shoptet.cz"
        },
        "Shopware": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Shopware.png",
            "implies": [
                "PHP",
                "MySQL",
                "jQuery"
            ],
            "meta": {
                "application-name": "Shopware"
            },
            "script": "(?:(shopware)|/web/cache/[0-9]{10}_.+)\\.js\\;version:\\1?4:5",
            "website": "shopware.com"
        },
        "Smartstore": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Smartstore.png",
            "script": "smjslib\\.js",
            "website": "smartstore.com"
        },
        "Spree": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "(?:<link[^>]*/assets/store/all-[a-z\\d]{32}\\.css[^>]+>|<script>\\s*Spree\\.(?:routes|translations|api_key))",
            "icon": "Spree.png",
            "implies": "Ruby on Rails",
            "website": "spreecommerce.com"
        },
        "Store Systems": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "Shopsystem von <a href=[^>]+store-systems\\.de\"|\\.mws_boxTop",
            "icon": "Store Systems.png",
            "website": "store-systems.de"
        },
        "Thelia": {
            "cats": [
                1,
                6
            ],
            "html": "<(?:link|style|script)[^>]+/assets/frontOffice/",
            "icon": "Thelia.png",
            "implies": [
                "PHP",
                "Symfony"
            ],
            "website": "thelia.net"
        },
        "TomatoCart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^AjaxShoppingCart$",
            "icon": "TomatoCart.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "TomatoCart"
            },
            "website": "tomatocart.com"
        },
        "Ubercart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Ubercart.png",
            "implies": "Drupal",
            "script": "uc_cart/uc_cart_block\\.js",
            "website": "www.ubercart.org"
        },
        "UltraCart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^ucCatalog",
            "html": "<form [^>]*action=\"[^\"]*\\/cgi-bin\\/UCEditor\\?(?:[^\"]*&)?merchantId=[^\"]",
            "icon": "UltraCart.png",
            "script": "cgi-bin\\/UCJavaScript\\?(?:[^\"]*&)?merchantid=.",
            "url": "/cgi-bin/UCEditor\\?(?:.*&)?merchantid=.",
            "website": "ultracart.com"
        },
        "VP-ASP": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<a[^>]+>Powered By VP-ASP Shopping Cart</a>",
            "icon": "VP-ASP.png",
            "implies": "Microsoft ASP.NET",
            "script": "vs350\\.js",
            "website": "www.vpasp.com"
        },
        "VTEX Enterprise": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "powered": "vtex"
            },
            "icon": "VTEX Enterprise.png",
            "website": "vtex.com"
        },
        "VTEX Integrated Store": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "X-Powered-By": "vtex-integrated-store"
            },
            "icon": "VTEX Integrated Store.png",
            "website": "lojaintegrada.com.br"
        },
        "Venda": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "X-venda-hitid": ""
            },
            "icon": "Venda.png",
            "website": "venda.com"
        },
        "VirtueMart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<div id=\"vmMainPage",
            "icon": "VirtueMart.png",
            "implies": "Joomla",
            "website": "virtuemart.net"
        },
        "Volusion": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^volusion$",
            "html": "<link [^>]*href=\"[^\"]*/vspfiles/",
            "icon": "Volusion.png",
            "script": "/volusion\\.js(?:\\?([\\d.]*))?\\;version:\\1",
            "website": "volusion.com"
        },
        "WHMCS": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "^WHMCS.*"
            },
            "icon": "WHMCS.png",
            "website": "www.whmcs.com"
        },
        "Websale": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Websale.png",
            "url": "/websale7/",
            "website": "websale.de"
        },
        "WooCommerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "woocommerce",
            "html": "<!-- WooCommerce",
            "icon": "WooCommerce.png",
            "implies": [
                "WordPress",
                "PHP"
            ],
            "meta": {
                "generator": "WooCommerce ([\\d.]+)\\;version:\\1"
            },
            "script": "woocommerce",
            "website": "www.woothemes.com/woocommerce"
        },
        "X-Cart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^(?:xcart_web_dir|xliteConfig)$",
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "xid=[a-z\\d]{32}(?:;|$)"
            },
            "html": [
                "Powered by X-Cart(?: (\\d+))? <a[^>]+href=\"http://www\\.x-cart\\.com/\"[^>]*>\\;version:\\1",
                "<a[^>]+href=\"[^\"]*(?:\\?|&)xcart_form_id=[a-z\\d]{32}(?:&|$)"
            ],
            "icon": "X-Cart.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "X-Cart(?: (\\d+))?\\;version:\\1"
            },
            "script": "/skin/common_files/modules/Product_Options/func\\.js",
            "website": "x-cart.com"
        },
        "Xanario": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Xanario.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "xanario shopsoftware"
            },
            "website": "xanario.de"
        },
        "Yahoo! Ecommerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "env": "^YStore$",
            "headers": {
                "X-XRDS-Location": "/ystore/"
            },
            "html": "<link[^>]+store\\.yahoo\\.net",
            "icon": "Yahoo! Ecommerce.png",
            "website": "smallbusiness.yahoo.com/ecommerce"
        },
        "Zen Cart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "Zen Cart.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "Zen Cart"
            },
            "website": "www.zen-cart.com"
        },
        "Zeuscart": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<form name=\"product\" method=\"post\" action=\"[^\"]+\\?do=addtocart&prodid=\\d+\"(?!<\\/form>.)+<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"addtocart\" value=\"\\d+\">",
            "icon": "Zeuscart.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "url": "\\?do=prodetail&action=show&prodid=\\d+",
            "website": "zeuscart.com"
        },
        "eZ Publish": {
            "cats": [
                1,
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "X-Powered-By": "^eZ Publish"
            },
            "icon": "eZ Publish.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "eZ Publish"
            },
            "website": "ez.no"
        },
        "iCongo": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "icon": "iCongo.png",
            "implies": "Adobe ColdFusion",
            "meta": {
                "iCongo": ""
            },
            "website": "hybris.com/icongo"
        },
        "nopCommerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "(?:<!--Powered by nopCommerce|Powered by: <a[^>]+nopcommerce)",
            "icon": "nopCommerce.png",
            "website": "www.nopcommerce.com"
        },
        "osCSS": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<body onload=\"window\\.defaultStatus='oscss templates';\"",
            "icon": "osCSS.png",
            "website": "www.oscss.org"
        },
        "osCommerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Set-Cookie": "osCsid="
            },
            "html": "(?:<a[^>]*(?:\\?|&)osCsid|Powered by (?:<[^>]+>)?osCommerce</a>|<[^>]+class=\"[^>]*infoBoxHeading)",
            "icon": "osCommerce.png",
            "website": "www.oscommerce.com"
        },
        "xtCommerce": {
            "cats": [
                6
            ],
            "html": "<div class=\"copyright\">[^<]+<a[^>]+>xt:Commerce",
            "icon": "xtCommerce.png",
            "meta": {
                "generator": "xt:Commerce"
            },
            "website": "www.xt-commerce.com"
        },
    }
};
// for each loop 
for(obj in technology){
        console.log('objects => ', obj);
    console.log('value => ', technology[obj]);
// do your job here 
}
```

you can inflate data to your view through this loop

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @abdallh-abukhader is correct, interestingly the reason it wont display out into the console is because of security restrictions on this line -

```
"html": "(?:<link[^>]*/assets/store/all-[a-z\\d]{32}\\.css[^>]+>|<script>\\s*Spree\\.(?:routes|translations|api_key))"
```

Chrome at least does not like the < s c r i p t > and blocks it - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Even stackoverflow wont let me type it properly.

Comment: Yeah you'll want to escape the HTML especially if you are printing it or sending it to a browser.

Answer (score 0):

How do you wish to iterate over this? For example, here's an example of printing every URL for each app:

```
for (var key in technology.apps) {
  console.log("The app is %s and its website is %s", key, technology.apps[key].icon);
}
```